# How can I demonstrate that delete does not deallocate all memory new [] allocates?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I want to write a simple application that proves that a memory leak exists if you use delete on a pointer that was allocated using new [].

I am currently using the CRT Debug library to monitor the memory in my application to capture the memory after allocation and after the improper deallocation. Please see my test code here:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    _CrtMemState s1, s2, mem_diff;

    // Allocate 40 bytes of memory.
    int *leak = new int[10];

    // Capture the memory state after the allocation.
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s1);

    // Deallocate that memory with incorrect delete operator.    
    delete leak;

    // Capture and compare the memory after the deallocation.
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s2);
    _CrtMemDifference(&mem_diff, &s1, &s2);
    _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&mem_diff);

    return 0;
}
```

However, in my debug output I'm see that all 40 bytes are being deallocated. This is the output from my debug console in Visual Studio 2015 Express:

```
0 bytes in 0 Free Blocks.
-40 bytes in -1 Normal Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 CRT Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Ignore Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Client Blocks.
Largest number used: 0 bytes.
Total allocations: 0 bytes.
```

My other idea for why this is working is that it's undefined behaviour and is compiler specific behaviour in this case.

Comment: Last sentence - that's a very reasonable interpretation ;)

Comment: Why do you expect that it will not deallocate everything?

Comment: It is known that for trivial types, like `int`, VC++ just happens to generate exactly the same code for `delete` and `delete[]`.

Comment: @Soren, I was reading about auto_ptr and it was recommended to never use auto_ptr to store a pointer to an array allocated by new [] because the auto_ptr will use the delete operator instead of the delete [] operator. I wanted to determine what happened in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void leak_via_wrong_delete() {
  std::vector<int>* buff = new std::vector<int>[1000];
  for (auto i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    buff[i].resize(i * 1000);
  delete buff;
}
```

Wrap this with your leak detection code.

In practice, the real reason why `delete[]` is important is that it calls the destructor of all of the elements in the array, in most implementations I know of.  (There may be one medium-obscure platform where it also fails catastrophically, I cannot recall).

For classes without trivial destruction, they store the number of elements (or something similar) in the bytes *before* the start of the allocated array.  Then `delete[]` examines it and destroys each object in turn.

Comment: I tried my test again with an array of objects instead of primitive types as you suggest, the CRT detects this while in debug mode and triggers a breakpoint so I couldn't continue to print my memory statistics. However, I examined the memory and it was exactly as you described, there was 4 bytes allocated just before my array which was storing the array size. This did not appear before my array containing the ints.